# Show that the closure of S in Y coincides with $\bar S \cap Y$

Tags: general-topology

As a novice, it is hard to prove the following problem.

Let Y be a subspace of a metric space X and let S be a subset of Y. Show that the closure of S in Y coincides with $\bar S \cap Y$, where $\bar S$ is the closure of S in X.

Comment: What is your definition of a subspace of a metric space? Is your metric space a vector space?

Comment: $Y \subset X$ and the restriction $d'$ of $d$ to $Y\times Y$ is a metric on $Y.$ Anyway it doesn't matter.

Comment: He means topological subspace.

Comment: Showing that $\textrm{cl}_Y(S \cap Y) \subset \textrm{cl}_X(S) \cap Y$, where $\textrm{cl}_M(A)$ means closure of $A$ in the metric space $M$, should be straight-forward. For the converse, what you need to show is that if a sequence in $S$ converges to a point in $Y$, then there's a sequence in $S \cap Y$ which converges to the same point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $S \subset Y$. Let $\bar{S}_Y$ denote its closure in $Y$. We want to prove $$ \bar{S}_Y = \bar{S}_X \cap Y$$ So it suffices to prove $(\bar{S}_X \cap Y) \subset \bar{S}_Y$ as the other side follows from definition of $\bar{S}_Y$.

Consider $x \in \bar{S}_X \cap Y$, then there exists a sequence $x_n \in S$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ under the given metric. Now by definition $x \in Y$, and so $x \in \bar{S}_Y$.

Thus $(\bar{S}_X \cap Y) \subset \bar{S}_Y$, and using the other inclusion we have both these sets equal.

Comment: Huh? To show that indeed $x \in \bar S_Y$, you need to find a *sequence* in $S \cap Y$ that converges to $x$. But $x \in \bar S_X \cap Y$ allows the *sequence* to lie in $S$, and only the *limit* to lie in $Y$! Imagine $Y$ to be the real line, $X$ to be $\mathbb{C}$, and $S$ to be the open unit square. What you need to show is that if there is a sequence in $S$ which converges to a real number $r$, then there's a sequence in $S \cap Y = (0,1)$ which converges to that $r$.

Comment: $S \subset Y$ here.

Comment: @DiffeoR Oh, missed that. Yup, then it's trivial ;-)